# Google Tag Manager in roku

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, roku

I would like to install Google Tag Manager in roku. There is any simple solution for doing this. I know that I can use Google Analytics but I would like to do some implementations using Google Tag Manager, working with the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

No, because from what i read (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6102821), "Google Tag Manager" is implemented only for web pages (via javascript) and iOS/Android mobile apps (+ Firebase SDK requirement). None of that is applicable to Roku.